# ¿por qué usar una clase abstracta y no crear métodos en una clase no abstracta?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buen dia,
Mi duda es ...¿por qué si al utilizar una clase abstracta , al heredar esta clase se e implementar las propiedades o métodos de esta clase,que beneficio me da hacer esto y no crear una clase no abstracta y crear los métodos directamente?

Espero y puedan ayudar a resolver mi duda.
Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La decision depende del modelo de objetos que quieras conseguir.

Puede que tengas `funcionalidad base comun`, pero cierto compartamiento sea concreto a cada a `clases derivadas`, entonces debes especifilarla puntualmente. No se si ese llega a ser tu caso.

No hay un conceto de beneficio o no, depende de que quieras conseguir.

Mas alla de la clase abstracta tienes `metodo abstractos` que son justament elos que debes definir concretamente.

[abstract (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

Si analizas el ejemplo

[Abstract Methods and Classes in C#](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/csharp/abstract)

veras que define una clase

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    protected string name;  
    public abstract string sound(); //all classes that implement Animal must have a sound method
} 

public class Cat : Animal 
{  
    public Cat() 
    {
        this.name = "Garfield";        
    }    

    override public string sound()
    { //implemented sound method from the abstract class & method
        return "Meow!";
    }
} 

public class Dog : Animal 
{  
    public Dog() 
    {
        this.name = "Pluto";        
    }    

    override public string sound()
    { 
        return "Guau!";
    }
}
```

Esta claro que no puedes instanciar la clase `Animal` porque de por si un animal no puede emitir ningun tipo de sonido, solo cuando creas una clase derivada es que pudes definirlo para ese animal en concreto.

Si tu caso define que una clase base no se puede instanciar porque no puede definir funcionalidad comun, entonces lo haces `abstract`, en cambio si determinas que la clase base es funcionalmente completa y se puede crear instancias directas dejala como una clase simple instanciable

Answer (score 0):

**Prioriza la composición(interfaz) en vez de la herecia.**

[Como se citó en Patrones de Diseño por "the Gang of Four"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), deberías priorizar la composición en vez de la herecia siempre que puedas. Hay muy buenas razones para usar tanto la herecia como la composición. El problema principal es que nuestra mente siempre tiende a la herencia como primera opción, pero deberíamos de pensar qué tan bien nos encaja la composición en ese caso particular porque en muchas ocasiones es lo más acertado.

> Entonces a como preguntas, ¿Cuando debería yo usar la herencia? Todo
>   depende. Depende del problema que tengas entre mano, pero ya hay
>   ocasiones particulares donde la herencia tiene más sentido que la
>   composición:

1. Tu herencia representa una relación "es un/a" en vez de "tiene un/a" (Humano->Animal  vs. Usuario->DetallesUsuario)
2. Puedes reutilizar código desde las clases base (Los humanos pueden moverse como animales)
3. Quieres hacer cambios generales a clases derivadas cambiando la clase base. (Cambiar el consumo de calorías a todos los animales mientras se mueven)